# Controller works fine locally but not on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I'm using carrierwave with amazon s3 and heroku to upload and store images. It works fine locally but for some reason the controller function "new" isn't being executed on heroku.
I've printed the params[:controller] & params[:action] to the view, and both of them are correct, so I'm not sure what the problem is.

Routes.rb

```
      Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :surroundings

  resources :headings

  resources :options

  resources :categories

  resources :mains

  resources :properties do


    resources :images, only: [:index, :new, :create, :destroy] do
    collection do 
    get 'update_main' 
    end

    end


    get 'addoption'
    post 'postoption'

end

root 'search#main'
get 'main' =>'search#main'
```

images_controller.rb

```
class ImagesController < ApplicationController




def new
#redirect_to property_images_path #used for trouble shooting - does not redirect
@property=Property.find(params[:property_id])
@image = Image.new

end


 def index
    @images = Property.find(params[:property_id]).images
  end



def update_main
#set the current main image to false
   r=Property.find(params[:property_id]).images.where("main" => true).first
   r.main=false unless r.nil?
   r.save unless r.nil?
   @image=Image.find(params[:main])
   @image.main=true;
   @image.save
 redirect_to property_images_path, notice: "The Image has been uploaded."
end


  def create
    @image = Image.new(image_params)
    @image.property_id=params[:property_id]
    if @image.save
      redirect_to property_images_path, notice: "The Image has been uploaded."
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @image = Image.find(params[:id])
    @image.destroy
    redirect_to property_images_path, notice:  "The Image  has been deleted."
  end

private
  def image_params
   params.require(:image).permit(:attachment,:property_id)
  end
end
```

new.html.erb

```
<h1>Add new image</h1>
<%=params[:controller]%>
<%=params[:action]%>


<%= form_for([@property,@image]) do |f| %>
 <%= label_tag("Select image file") %>
   <%= f.file_field :attachment, class:"btn btn-default" %> 

<br>

    <%= f.submit class:"btn btn-primary" %>

<% end %>
```

heroku error logs

```
Processing by ImagesController#new as HTML
2016-02-06T07:43:25.314010+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"property_id"=>"1"}
2016-02-06T07:43:25.519196+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/properties/1/images/new" host=auspropguides.herokuapp.com request_id=ecaefc40-5556-4239-9da6-1a154fa489f3 fwd="14.201.25.50" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=391ms status=500 bytes=1754
2016-02-06T07:43:25.509640+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered images/new.html.erb within layouts/application (1.9ms)
2016-02-06T07:43:25.512962+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-02-06T07:43:25.512964+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty):
2016-02-06T07:43:25.509818+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 196ms
2016-02-06T07:43:25.512968+00:00 app[web.1]:     7:  <%= label_tag("Select image file") %>
2016-02-06T07:43:25.512969+00:00 app[web.1]:     8:    <%= f.file_field :attachment, class:"btn btn-default" %> 
2016-02-06T07:43:25.512965+00:00 app[web.1]:     3: <%=params[:action]%>
2016-02-06T07:43:25.512967+00:00 app[web.1]:     5: 
2016-02-06T07:43:25.512968+00:00 app[web.1]:     6: <%= form_for([@property,@image]) do |f| %>
2016-02-06T07:43:25.512966+00:00 app[web.1]:     4: 
2016-02-06T07:43:25.512971+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/images/new.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_images_new_html_erb___892626609660663212_69968138740340'
2016-02-06T07:43:25.512972+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-02-06T07:43:25.512970+00:00 app[web.1]:     9: 
2016-02-06T07:43:25.512972+00:00 app[web.1]:
```

Console log

```
irb(main):001:0> Property.find(1)
  Property Load (2.2ms)  SELECT  "properties".* FROM "properties" WHERE "properties"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Property Load (2.2ms)  SELECT  "properties".* FROM "properties" WHERE "properties"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
=> #<Property id: 1, listing_status: "In Draft", my_property_reference: "My reference", floor_area: 350, land_area: 500, state: "New Development", city: "Sydney", area: "CBD", street: "123 fake st", price: 800000, floors: 2, property_type: "Apartment", property_age: nil, completion: 2016, bedrooms: 5, bathrooms: 2, under_cover_car_spaces: 3, car_spaces: nil, car_lock_up_garage: 1, additional_information: "Great location in a great area.", description: "great house great house great house great house gr...", created_at: "2016-02-04 03:44:54", updated_at: "2016-02-04 03:46:55", suburb: nil>
irb(main):002:0> Image.all
  Image Load (1.8ms)  SELECT "images".* FROM "images"
  Image Load (1.8ms)  SELECT "images".* FROM "images"
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
irb(main):003:0> Image
=> Image(id: integer, main: boolean, attachment: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, property_id: integer)
irb(main):004:0>
```

Comment: please include your view code of new.html

Comment: <%= "property is nil" if @property.nil? %> 2016-02-06T07:15:35.551495+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty)

Comment: `@property=Property.find(params[:property_id])` this is resulting to `nil` in your heroku db, validate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that since you've nested `images` under `properties`, you'll have to declare both `@instance` variables if you want to get the `form_for` to work:

```
def new
  @property = Property.find params[:property_id]
  @image    = Image.new
end
```

Of course, you do this already.

The problem, then, is that your `Property` with an `id` of `1` doesn't exist on your Production environment. You need to make sure you're handling your data-set with the same care as you would development (evaluating if dependent objects don't exist):

```
def new
   @property = Property.find params[:property_id]
   if @property 
      @image = @property.images.new
   else
     redirect_to root_path, notice: "No Property" 
   end
end
```

---

You'll also want to define [multiple `resources` at once](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#defining-multiple-resources-at-the-same-time) in your `routes` (to clean it up):

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :surroundings, :headings, :options, :categories, :mains
resources :properties do
  resources :images, only: [:index, :new, :create, :destroy] do
    get 'update_main', on: :collection
  end
  get  :addoption
  post :postoption
end

resources :search, path: "", only: [] do
  get :main, on: :collection
end

root 'search#main'
```

---

**Update**

The solution was trivial, the OP left a `photos_controller.rb` file with `class ImagesController < ApplicationController` declaration. Removing this file fixed the issue.

Comment: thanks, I updated the new function. However i'm getting the same error. Using the rails console on heroku it shows that there is a property with id 1 in the database. The images database is currently empty but I can access it via the console so i know it exists.

Comment: Can you show me the console log for the request please?

Comment: added the console log

Comment: Is this from local or Heroku?

Comment: from  'heroku run rails c'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102778/discussion-between-rich-peck-and-kim-bedson).